# Creating a lighter than air model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all.

I would like to create a lighter than air model in Gazebo that can be,  at first, just a balloon. I would like to  know if there is some standard way to build this kind of model and, if so, where can I find reference materials (documentation, article, book) on how to do it. Any information will be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17448/creating-a-lighter-than-air-model/) by [randerson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3916/randerson/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use the buoyancy plugin, take a look at the tutorial:

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=hydrodynamics&cat=plugins

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [randerson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3916/randerson/) on 2017-10-07**:
It is a great start. Thanks. But, for the specific case of an airship, the Aerodynamics plugin would be more appropriate, right? Or, should I stick with the Hydrodynamics one?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-09**:
The aerodynamics `LiftDrag` plugin could be used to propel your airship and the buoyancy plugin could be used to keep it afloat, take a look at the submarine model as an example: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/220aa60a2eaa5f31b52429d08c8e94bd05646e23/submarine/model.sdf?fileviewer=file-view-default#model.sdf-190